# flask-socketio doesn't see overridden resource

Tags: python, socket.io, gevent-socketio, flask-socketio

This is a simple flask-socketio server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, send, emit, join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('connected')
    emit('response', {'status':'ok'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

which gets connected to like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
        socket.emit('connect');
    });
    socket.on('response', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

so when I open the page I see in the browser console:

```
(index):6 connected
(index):10 Object {status: "ok"}
```

but when I change the resource on the frontend:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port, {resource:'resource2'});
```

and on the backend:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, resource='resource2')
```

I only see this

```
(index):6 connected
```

so nothing gets emitted. Also, the backend doesn't call `print('connected')`.

What's wrong with resource overrides?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this as well. My first guess is that this is a bug in gevent-socketio, as far as I can see Flask-SocketIO is passing the resource name down to it. I need to debug it some more to figure out where the problem is.